# The eigenvalue of Schrodinger opeartor

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider $L=\Delta+V$ where $\Delta=div\nabla$. According to section 8.12 in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book, if $V\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, then the Dirichlet spectrum of $L$ exists, and the first eigenvalue is simple.

(1) What is the weakest condition on $V$ such that the spectrum still exists?

(2) What is the condition on $V$ such that the first eigenvalue is positive?

I think this should be well studied, but I haven't been able to find any good reference. If you are familiar with this, please let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by weakest? (for question 1) // For your second question, as you wrote it, your operator $L$ is formally a negative operator when $V \equiv 0$. I just want to double check that you really meant to ask about the first eigenvalue being positive, or if rather you want the opposite direction? In any case, certainly the answer to the second question depends lots on $\Omega$ and details of $V$, if only just by thinking about the family $\lambda V$ of potentials and noting for all sufficiently small $\lambda$ the spectrum should be a small perturbation of that of $\Delta$.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! What precisely do you mean by "the spectrum exists"? Every linear operator has a spectrum by definition.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: I deleted my previous comment because my interpretation was not correct. Turns out that particular section of G+T is talking about Rayleigh quotients, and bounded coefficients are convenient. // And also, never noticed this before, but there is a typo in the 2001 edition of G+T: the operator and quadratic form on the bottom of page 212 disagree by a sign (which further muddies my second question to the OP).

Comment: One possibility (after taking a quick look at G+T) of a reasonable question: what are the conditions on $V$ that guarantees the spectrum is discrete. Perhaps this is what the OP meant by question 1.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, that's what I meant. Can we have weaker conditions like $V\in L^p(\Omega)$ such that the operator has a discrete increasing spectrum? However, I am more interested about the second one.

Comment: I would recommend the book by B. Davies: spectral theory and differential operators.

Comment: @Student: The question which unbounded types of potentials are admissible depends heavily on the sign of the potential. If you are interested in $V$ that are bounded above (but not necessarily below), things are easier than if you are interested in $V$ that might be unbounded above.